# Shorten string list by generating wildcard expression

Tags: compression, pattern-matching, wildcard

I am given a list `L` of strings, each of a given, constant length (think 8-character identifiers). `L` can be assumed as constant and will be stored, e.g. in a database.

The task is to test if a string `s` is contained in the list. `s` can be different for each test.

If `L` gets very long, this method is becoming inefficient both in terms of storage and processing time.

I am looking for a method to shorten the list by generating a wildcard expression of some type (maybe a Regex or a simple `*`/`?` pattern) that can be stored instead of the list (or together with the list) and later be matched against.

Comment: Wouldn't a trie be a good choice?  You only need eight character comparisons if the value exists and less if it doesn't.

Comment: Yes, that could be. Since the identifiers are chosen from a list they tend to have common suffixes (not prefixes) so that the trie would be from right to left.

Comment: — wrong explanation. They do have common prefixes of course, the wildcard would be the suffix…

Comment: Are you trying to find if the string `s` is a _substring_ of any string in the list, or does it have to match exactly? That is, will `s` always be 8 characters also?

Comment: The test is if `s` matches any of the elements of `L`. Every identifier involved can be assumed to have (e.g.) 8 characters. In practice, some identifiers in `L` or the test string `s` could be shorter, but this is equivalent since these could be padded with a fill character.